# How can I get this async result before the rest of the code?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have read a lot about async and  Promise and I just cant get my head around it.

to put it simple:

```
let test = 50;

check(array).then(x => console.log("this goes first",x));
console.log(test);
```

my async function in another class:

```
async check(array) {
   let b;
   for (let word of array)  
      b = (await check(word)) ? 0 : 1;         //if true =0  , false =1
      if (oneElemInArrayisFalse === 1) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return b;
  }
```

my output is:

```
50
"this goes first:"(1 or 0)
```

instead of the other-way around...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to know hot to print the resut of the the Async function and then continue with the rest of the code. In this case ```console.log(test)```

Comment: You need to move that `console.log(test);` either inside the `then` callback or after an `await`. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain thens:

```
let test = 50;

check(array)
   .then(x => console.log("this goes first",x))
   .then(() => console.log(test));
```

Comment: that is what I tried to do here: ```check(array).then(x => console.log("this goes first",x));```

Comment: You should not chain `then` calls if the first callback doesn't return a promise. The second callback won't receive an `x` argument either.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the logic in the "then" your code continues, and whenever the promise returns, the then will happen (like a callback function).. you could await, like this (you would need the calling function to be async):

```
let test = 50;
let x = await check(array);
console.log("this goes first",x);
console.log(test);
```

Where the log will happen in order of course, but what can show you this works is that x will be returned and not `undefined`..
If you can't make the calling function async, you could just put everything that should happen after the check in the `then`..

```
let test = 50;
check(array).then(x => {
 console.log("this goes first",x);
 console.log(test);
);
```

Since you want the rest of the code run run synchronously, you don't need to have them happen in different places..
do notice that anything after the `then` will not run synchronously, and could happen before the check function returns

Comment: You forgot to mention that `await` can only be used in `async` functions

Comment: I cant do that because await has to be in the async method :(

Comment: Thought you could change the calling method to be async, I edited my answer.. but notice the explanation about the then.. that's what I was going for mostly..